# Transparent Video Background

Tags: rendering

I have a series of PNGs that have transparent backgrounds.  When I place them on the strip in Video Editing and render, the background on the video is black.

I've made certain that the Transparent box is checked, and that any file formats, container or codec selections allow for RGBA, before rendering animation.  Still, the background of the video turns out black!

The file is here, and I'm desperate (and appreciative) for direction:
[waving flag](https://jumpshare.com/v/g2fWjWqg1d2VDD1VuBVM)

I would like to render the PNG files, within the Sequencer, as an mp4, WITH A TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND.  Hope this is descriptive enough to gather a response?

Comment: Did you expressly set a background color?

Comment: What is your preferred final output?  AVI ... FFMpeg? PNG?

Comment: Please show your desired settings as a well planned Blender screen capture.

Comment: **What's your question?** How to compile a video file with transparent background? If so, you'll have to encode your files to 10bit prores/dnxhd or avi uncompressed which I don't think is supported by blender, Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avid_DNxHD

Comment: Do you want to render PNGs from a collection of other PNGs?

Comment: atomicbezierslinger - My entire project is hyperlinked above, i.e. waving flag.  If you could look at that, it would answer your questions.  Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

Expressly set a background to the color of your choice.
Shift A ... then choose color.  Show the sidebar with N.
Then pick a new color such as blue or red.  For many video types  there is no transparency, there is a final color calculated, which may be black by default.

If you are merging transparent PNGs into a sequence of PNGs, then choose a sequence of you PNGs as your output.  There is also OpenEXR which may require a little more work to see in your default operating system if the occasion arises.

Comment: If the question is how to compile a transparent video file out of RGBA pngs, this answer is way off.

Comment: Yes, Brockmann, the question is "How to render a video file with a transparent background, using PNG image in sequence.

Comment: Could please add that to your question as requested to re-open it? Also see [my comment here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168026/transparent-video-background/168036#comment283517_168026)  @jmarkt

Comment: As it turns out, in spite of the background being black, it DOES produce transparency when rendered as Alpha Over and placed over a video strip in VSE.